# Crystal reports datasource with references

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reporting, objectdatasource, crystal-reports-2010

I am new with crystal reports and have one problem. I need subreport or grouping in table, but problem is that I have two clases Group and Foo, Group has List and I need grouping via Group.Name and display data from Foo.

For example:

```
    public class Group
    {
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public List<Group> Children{get;set}
        public Group ParentGroup{get;set;}
        public List<Foo> Items{get;set;}
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public string Number{get;set;}
        public double Price{get;set;}
        public double Quantity{get;set;}
    }
```

and I want get report grouped by Group.Name and see Foo detail

For example:

Group1

---

|Name  |  Number  | Quantity  | Price  | TotalPrice |

---

|Pen   |  01      | 3 | 15 | 45|

|Eraser   |  14      | 1 | 20 | 20|

How is the best way to do it? Data is not in database, its only as object in c#. But real problem is reference Group.Items

Thanks for help. Jakub

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:
Pull out two data tables from database in a single SP.

1. For the group name and other details as header table, and
2. From the details based on the group name or id.
3. Bind these two tables two your crystal report.

Comment: Data isn't in database, its in object in c# application. I thing I can do something like add GroupID and join between Group and Foo, but it is horrible solution.

Comment: Then use Ienumerable collection for the same. See this http://www.amergerzic.com/post/IEnumerableCrystalReports.aspx

Comment: Thats not problem. Problem is in database it would be table Group with ID and table FOO with Group_ID. Then I can use GroupID like parameter in subreport and use linq Where(q=>ParamGroupID==Group_ID).
But I havent Group_ID, I have reference from Class Group to IEnumerable Items. Question is:
How to add Datasource for subreport reference from class Group to this Items without something like inner linq query. I cannot see Items in Fields Explorer

Comment: Maybe if there is way, how to set subreports datasource for each grouped part. But I cant find how to do this